# Read text file. If same input, print "Existed"

Tags: c, text

Here is the text file data :

The value 78, 2, 98 are the productID.

```
78 MINERALWATER 123 345.00
2 RAYBAN 2 450.00
98 ADIDASWATCH 19 200.00
```

If user enter input which is the same as productID above. How can I print, "The product already exist!"

Here is the part of code I already alter in `int addProduct()`.

```
    printf("Enter product ID : ");
    scanf(" %d", &a.id);

    productID = a.id;

    fp = fopen("inventory.txt","r");
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price)==4)
        {
            ///The Output Came From Text File Must Be Same As User Instructed
            if(a.id == productID)
            {
            printf("The item already exist!");
            }
            else{
                 gotoxy(22,10);
    printf("Enter product name : ");
    scanf(" %s", a.name);

    gotoxy(22,12);
    printf("Enter product quantity : ");
    scanf(" %d", &a.quantity);

    gotoxy(22,14);
    printf("Enter product price : ");
    scanf(" %f", &a.price);


    gotoxy(22,17);
    ///Store @ Write Product Data Inside FP Text File
    fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);

    printf("Record saved!\n\n");

            }
        }
```

User input value 2 and store at `a.id`. Then, compiler scan the whole file, if `a.id = productID`, then print Item already exist. Else, continue adding new product.

But, it fails. Compiler keep on adding data although user input value 2 and text file became :

```
78 MINERALWATER 123 345.00
2 RAYBAN 2 450.00
98 ADIDASWATCH 19 200.00
2 NEWITEM 4 219.00
```

Here is my full code without altercation of looping if same productID was exist : point of interest is on `int addProduct()`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>

///Function Prototype
void gotoxy( int column, int line );
int main();
int addProduct();
int displayProduct();
int searchProduct();
int reorderProduct();
int updateProduct();

///Global Variables
struct product
{
    int quantity, reorder, i, id;
    char name[20];
    float price;
};

COORD coord = {0, 0};

///GotoXY Function
void gotoxy (int x, int y)
{
coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;

SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

///Main Function
int main()
{
    int choice;

        ///GotoXY Output
        gotoxy(17,5);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        gotoxy(17,20);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        ///Menu Display
        gotoxy(22,8);
        printf("1. Add Product\n\n");

        gotoxy(22,10);
        printf("2. Display Product\n\n");

        gotoxy(22,12);
        printf("3. Search Product\n\n");

        gotoxy(22,14);
        printf("4. Reorder Level of Product\n\n");

        gotoxy(22,16);
        printf("5. Update Product\n\n");

        gotoxy(22,18);
        printf("6. Exit\n\n");

        ///Choice Input
        gotoxy(22,22);
        printf("Please Enter Your Choice : ");
        scanf(" %d", &choice);

        ///Choice Using Switch Case
        switch(choice)
            {
            case 1 :    addProduct();
                        break;

            case 2 :    displayProduct();
                        break;

            case 3 :    searchProduct();
                        break;

            case 4 :    reorderProduct();
                        break;

            case 5 :    updateProduct();
                        break;

            case 6 :    break;

            default :   system("cls");
                        main();

            }
return (0);
}


///Add Product Function
int addProduct()
{
    ///File Pointer
    FILE * fp;
    int number;
    char checker;
    struct product a;

    ///Clear Screen On Command Prompt
    system("cls");

    ///FP Text File is Open. A = Append
    fp = fopen("inventory.txt","a+t");

        ///Do-While Loop For Product Input
        do
        {
        system("cls");

        ///GotoXY Output
        gotoxy(17,5);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        gotoxy(17,20);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        ///4 Input Of Add Product | Product ID | Product Name | Product Quantity | Product Price |
        gotoxy(22,8);
        printf("Enter product ID : ");
        scanf(" %d", &a.id);

        gotoxy(22,10);
        printf("Enter product name : ");
        scanf(" %s", a.name);

        gotoxy(22,12);
        printf("Enter product quantity : ");
        scanf(" %d", &a.quantity);

        gotoxy(22,14);
        printf("Enter product price : ");
        scanf(" %f", &a.price);


        gotoxy(22,17);
        ///Store @ Write Product Data Inside FP Text File
        fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);

        printf("Record saved!\n\n");

        ///Close FP Text File
        fclose(fp);


        ///Choice Input For User Enter New Product Or Back To Main
        gotoxy(22,22);
        printf("Do you want to enter new product? Y / N : ");

        scanf(" %c", &checker);

        ///Change To Uppercase, If User Enter Lowercase Character
        checker = toupper(checker);

        system("cls");
        }
        ///If Checker Input is Y @ Yes : Continue Loop Adding Product
        while(checker=='Y');

            ///If Checker Input Is N @ No : Back To Main
            if(checker == 'N')
                {
                main();
                }

            else
            {
                do
                {
                system("cls");

                ///GotoXY Output
                gotoxy(17,5);
                printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

                gotoxy(17,20);
                printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

                gotoxy(18,8);
                printf(">>> Wrong Input! Please Enter Y Or N Only! <<<");

                gotoxy(19,12);
                printf("Do You Want To Enter New Product? Y / N : ");
                scanf(" %c", &checker);

                ///Change To Uppercase, If User Enter Lowercase Character
                checker = toupper(checker);
                }
                ///Keep On Looping If User Enter Other Than Y Or N.
                while(checker != 'Y' && checker != 'N');

                ///If Input Y : Add Product
                if(checker == 'Y')  {   addProduct();  }

                ///If Input N : Back To Main
                if(checker == 'N')  {   system("cls");
                                        main();
                                    }

            }

return(0);
}


///Display Product Function
int displayProduct()
{
    ///File Pointer
    FILE * fp;

    struct product a;
    system("cls");

    ///FP Text File is Open. R = Read Only
    fp = fopen("inventory.txt","r");

        ///GotoXY Output
        gotoxy(17,5);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        gotoxy(5,6);
        printf("======================================================================");

        ///Table Title
        gotoxy(5,7);
        printf("Product ID\t\t Product Name\t\t Quantity\t Unit Price\n");

        gotoxy(5,8);
        printf("======================================================================");

        ///Content Of Text File Is Read And Store Into Variables
        gotoxy(0,10);
        while(fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price)==4)
        {
        ///List Of Product From Text File Is Display On Command Prompt
        printf("\t%-10d\t %-12s\t\t %8d\t %8.2f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
        }

        ///Close FP Text File
        fclose(fp);

        ///GotoXY Output
        printf("\t\t \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        printf("\n\n\t\t    >> Press any key to return to Main Menu <<");

    getch();
    system("cls");

    ///Back To Main Function
    main();

return (0);
}



int searchProduct()
{
    ///File Pointer
    FILE * fp;

    system("cls");
    struct product a;
    int productID;

    ///FP Text File is Open. R = Read Only
    fp = fopen("inventory.txt","r");

        ///GotoXY Output
        gotoxy(17,5);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        gotoxy(17,20);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        ///Input Product ID Want To Search
        gotoxy(22,8);
        printf("Please enter product ID : ");
        scanf(" %d", &productID);

        gotoxy(5,10);
        printf("======================================================================");

        ///Table Title
        gotoxy(5,12);
        printf("Product ID\t\t Product Name\t\t Quantity\t Unit Price\n");

        gotoxy(5,14);
        printf("======================================================================");


            gotoxy(0,16);
            ///Content Of Text File Is Read And Store Into Variables
            while(fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price)==4)
            {
                ///The Output Came From Text File Must Be Same As User Instructed
                if(a.id == productID)
                {
                printf("\t%-10d\t %-12s\t\t %8d\t %8.2f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
                }
            }

        ///Close FP Text File
        fclose(fp);
        gotoxy(17,20);
        printf("\n\n\t\t    >> Press any key to return to Main Menu <<");

    getch();
    system("cls");
    main();

return(0);
}


int reorderProduct()
{
    ///File Pointer
    FILE * fp;

    system("cls");
    struct product a;
    int productQuantity;

    ///FP Text File is Open. R = Read Only
    fp = fopen("inventory.txt","r");

        ///GotoXY Output
        gotoxy(17,5);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        ///Input Minimum Product Quantity
        gotoxy(22,8);
        printf("Please enter minimum reorder level : ");
        scanf(" %d", &productQuantity);

        gotoxy(5,10);
        printf("======================================================================");

        ///Table Title
        gotoxy(5,12);
        printf("Product ID\t\t Product Name\t\t Quantity\t Unit Price\n");

        gotoxy(5,14);
        printf("======================================================================");

        gotoxy(0,16);
        ///Content Of Text File Is Read And Store Into Variables
        while(fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price)==4)
        {
            if(productQuantity >= a.quantity)
            {
            ///The Output Came From Text File Must Be Greater Or Equal As User Instructed (Item Need To Be Reorder)
            printf("\t%-10d\t %-12s\t\t %8d\t %8.2f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
            }
        }

        ///Close FP Text File
        fclose(fp);

        ///GotoXY Output
        printf("\t\t \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        printf("\n\n\t\t    >> Press any key to return to Main Menu <<");

    getch();
    system("cls");
    main();

return (0);
}



int updateProduct()
{
    ///File Pointer
    FILE *fp, *fp2;

    system("cls");
    struct product a;
    int productID;

    ///FP Text File is Open. R = Read Only
    fp = fopen("inventory.txt","r");
    rewind(fp);

    ///FP Text File is Open. R = Read Only
    fp2 = fopen("temporary.txt" ,"a");

        ///GotoXY Output
        gotoxy(17,5);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2 SYZ INVENTORY PROGRAM \xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        gotoxy(17,20);
        printf("\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2\xB2");

        ///Input Product ID To Be Update
        gotoxy(22,8);
        printf("Enter product ID : ");
        scanf(" %d", &productID);

        ///Content Of Text File FP Is Read
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
        ///Content Is Store Into Variables
        fscanf(fp, "%d %s %d %f", &a.id, a.name, &a.quantity, &a.price);

            if (feof(fp)) { continue; }

            if (a.id == productID) continue;

            fprintf(fp2, "%d %s %d %f\n\n", a.id, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);

        }

        ///Close FP Text File
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(fp2);

        ///Inventory Text File Is Remove
        remove("inventory.txt");
        ///Temporary Text File Is Rename Into Inventory Text File
        rename("temporary.txt", "inventory.txt");

        ///FP Text File is Open. R = Append
        fp = fopen("inventory.txt","a+t");

        ///3 Input Of Add Product | Product Name | Product Quantity | Product Price |
        gotoxy(22,10);
        printf("Enter product name : ");
        scanf(" %s", a.name);

        gotoxy(22,12);
        printf("Enter product quantity : ");
        scanf(" %d", &a.quantity);

        gotoxy(22,14);
        printf("Enter product price : ");
        scanf(" %f", &a.price);

        gotoxy(22,17);
        ///Store @ Write Product Data Inside FP Text File
        fprintf(fp, "%d %s %d %f\n\n", productID, a.name, a.quantity, a.price);
        printf("Record saved!\n\n");

        ///Close FP Text File
        fclose(fp);

        printf("\n\n\t\t    >> Press any key to return to Main Menu <<");

    getch();
    system("cls");
    main();

return(0);
}
```

Comment: You should have learned by now we are no debugging service.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, I do. But I just want to know, whether the constraint is correct ? if(a.id == productID)

Comment: Well, it can be valid C. For the rest, read your code, use a debugger, etc. Just normal procedure when writing code.

Comment: add record after examining all the records. (not else-block in loop).

Comment: And that code is awfully indented, too.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you mean starting from product name must be outside the while loop ?

Comment: @Olaf haha. sorry, its my 1st language. still learning :) thank you for pointing it out .

Comment: yes, move to outside of while-loop. (and need `a.id = productID` before new record write to file. also need reopen or change  open mode of file)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY how if we need append the file. then next read the file only ? its confusing.

Comment: `bool exist = false;`..`if(a.id == productID) { printf("The item already exist!"); exist = true; break; }`.. `if(exist != true){ /* add record */ }`

Comment: You don't have to show the entire program. Just show the parts you have trouble with, plus other code required to run the program (for example add function + read functions + `main` + file format). See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will also help you understand the problem instead of getting lost in a large program. If BLUEPIXY's comment has answered your question please edit the question and remove the irrelevant parts.

Comment: this line, in the prototype types is WRONG.  Do not prototype `main()`   The other prototypes, like: `int addProduct();` is not correct.  It says that the there ARE parameters, but the programmer is just to lazy to list them.  The function signature is ok, but the prototype should be: `int addProduct( void );`   Similar comments apply to the other prototypes

Comment: change the file opening mode to `r+` so can both read and write the file AND the file will not be truncated when first opened

Comment: there is no magic!,  the code must read every record to see if the user entered productID is already in the file.   Since the file is small and reading the whole file over and over is very time consuming.  Suggest a dynamically allocated array that contains all the productIDs then it would be a simple loop to scan the table to check if the user entered ID is already there,  Note the new productID would have to be added to the table as each new product is added.